# PHP - get response from external java form

Tags: php

using the php script I need to get the answer from the JAVA form that is on the external site. I'm trying to do this by using the CURL request. Unfortunately, the answer is always empty.

site with form (for example try 36471224):

[enter link description here](https://portal.unionzp.sk/onlinepobocka/pub/zoznam-dlznikov)

My php:

```
$post_page = "https://portal.unionzp.sk/onlinepobocka/pub/zoznam-dlznikov";
$cin = "36741621";

$page = file_get_contents($post_page);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach ($links as $link){
    if (strpos($link->getAttribute('name'), 'javax.faces.ViewState') !== false) {
        $ViewState = $link->getAttribute('value');
    }
    if (strpos($link->getAttribute('name'), '_csrf') !== false) {
        $csrf = $link->getAttribute('value');
    }
}

$request = 'javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=j_idt128%3Aj_idt133&javax.faces.partial.execute=%40all&javax.faces.partial.render=j_idt128%3Atable&j_idt128%3Aj_idt133=j_idt128%3Aj_idt133&j_idt128=j_idt128&_csrf='.$csrf.'&j_idt128%3AvyhladajPodla_input='.$cin.'&j_idt128%3AvyhladajPodla_hinput='.$cin.'&javax.faces.ViewState='.$ViewState;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $post_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($content);
```

does anyone know how to advise me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Curl can't execute JavaScript on external links. For similar propose I have used [Facebook php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) and phantomJS as a server to emulate the browser.

**EDIT**

Something like that.
To start phantomJS server:

```
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=127.0.0.1:4444 2>/dev/null &
```

And than:

```
<?php

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\UselessFileDetector;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\LocalFileDetector;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverElement;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverCommandExecutor;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', array(
        WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME    => 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A5297c Safari/602.1',
    ), 5000);
$driver->get('YOUR_LINK');
$html = $driver->getPageSource(); // to get page source
$button = $driver->findElement(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::className('normalButton'));
$button->click(); // to click the button with class=normalButton
```

Comment: @LubosBelan better - to install latest version of phantomJS from sources.